Reset counter when it encounters a zero in the column



date
customer
orders
desired result




31-Mar
cus1
1
1


01-Apr
cus1
1
2


02-Apr
cus1
0
0


03-Apr
cus1
0
0


04-Apr
cus1
1
1


05-Apr
cus1
1
2


06-Apr
cus1
1
3


07-Apr
cus1
1
4


08-Apr
cus1
1
5


09-Apr
cus1
1
6


01-Apr
cus2
0
0


02-Apr
cus2
0
0


03-Apr
cus2
1
1


04-Apr
cus2
1
2


05-Apr
cus2
1
3


06-Apr
cus2
0
0


07-Apr
cus2
1
1









Here  I have a table with dates , customers and their orders... i want a column to look like desired result in order to get my report functional. How can i do this using sql?
I have tried
row_number() over(partition by customer_id,desired_result order by work_date)
but that doesnot work,
what it does is this  - current results



date
customer
orders
desired result
current results




31-Mar
cus1
1
1
1


01-Apr
cus1
1
2
2


02-Apr
cus1
0
0
1


03-Apr
cus1
0
0
2


04-Apr
cus1
1
1
3


05-Apr
cus1
1
2
4


06-Apr
cus1
1
3
5


07-Apr
cus1
1
4
6


08-Apr
cus1
1
5
7


09-Apr
cus1
1
6
8


01-Apr
cus2
0
0
1


02-Apr
cus2
0
0
2


03-Apr
cus2
1
1
1


04-Apr
cus2
1
2
2


05-Apr
cus2
1
3
3


06-Apr
cus2
0
0
3


07-Apr
cus2
1
1
4




select x.*, row_number() over(partition by g order by date) + orders from (select t.*, count(case when orders = 0 then 1 end) over(order by date) as g from t) x ?

with data(dat,  customer, orders, desired_result) as (
    select to_date('31-03', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 1 from dual union all
    select to_date('01-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 2 from dual union all
    select to_date('02-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 0, 0 from dual union all
    select to_date('03-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 0, 0 from dual union all
    select to_date('04-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 1 from dual union all
    select to_date('05-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 2 from dual union all
    select to_date('06-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 3 from dual union all
    select to_date('07-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 4 from dual union all
    select to_date('08-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 5 from dual union all
    select to_date('09-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus1', 1, 6 from dual union all
    select to_date('01-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 0, 0 from dual union all
    select to_date('02-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 0, 0 from dual union all
    select to_date('03-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 1, 1 from dual union all
    select to_date('04-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 1, 2 from dual union all
    select to_date('05-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 1, 3 from dual union all
    select to_date('06-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 0, 0 from dual union all
    select to_date('07-04', 'DD-MM'), 'cus2', 1, 1 from dual -- union all
)
select d.dat, d.customer, d.orders,  
    case when orders <> 0 then row_number() over(partition by customer || 
        '-' || decode(orders,0,0,1) || '-' || cn  order by dat) else 0 end as rn
from (
    select d.*,
        sum(case when orders = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customer order by dat) as cn
    from data d
) d
order by customer, dat
;

31/03/24    cus1    1   1
01/04/24    cus1    1   2
02/04/24    cus1    0   0
03/04/24    cus1    0   0
04/04/24    cus1    1   1
05/04/24    cus1    1   2
06/04/24    cus1    1   3
07/04/24    cus1    1   4
08/04/24    cus1    1   5
09/04/24    cus1    1   6
01/04/24    cus2    0   0
02/04/24    cus2    0   0
03/04/24    cus2    1   1
04/04/24    cus2    1   2
05/04/24    cus2    1   3
06/04/24    cus2    0   0
07/04/24    cus2    1   1

Or with MATCH_RECOGNIZE:
SELECT dat,
       customer,
       orders,
       CASE  WHEN orders <> 0 THEN rn ELSE 0 END AS rn
FROM   data
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY customer
         ORDER BY dat
         MEASURES
           COUNT(orders) AS rn
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( WITH_ORDER+ | WITHOUT_ORDERS )
         DEFINE WITH_ORDER AS orders <> 0
       );


this works like a charm, thanks mate! I learnt something new as well. Much thanks!
